# When exactly to use "hartnäckig"

Tags: meaning-in-context

According to many dictionaries, *hartnäckig* means something along the lines of *persistent*, but I don't know exactly when I should use it. Does it have a bad connotation (like "stubborn")? Is it more common in everyday speech or in written language?

Answer (score 3):

*Hartnäckig* does not have a pejorative meaning by itself, but it is most commonly used in a context with a negative statement.

The first example on [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/hartn%C3%A4ckig) conveys a disapproving sense:

> Unser Lehrer bleibt immer so hartnäckig bei seiner Meinung.

Loosely translated, "Our teacher always remains adamant about his own opinion".
You could replace it with *stur* (*stubborn*) here, which gives even more emphasis on the negativity of the statement.

So, when you refer to insisting on one's opinion in an obstinate manner, *hartnäckig* certainly conveys a negative sense.

So, another example: a persistent cough, in German *hartnäckiger Husten*, is obviously very annoying and the word *hartnäckig* has a tendency towards negativity. Again, it's basically about the context. Even without the word *hartnäckig*, the cough is quite an aggravating thing, but the fact that is maintains makes it really nasty.

So, now an example with a positive sense, taken from from [zeit.de](http://www.zeit.de/digital/games/2011-02/mcgonigal-games-2).

> Sie arbeiten hartnäckig am Erfolg, geben nicht auf und meistern so die schwierigsten Aufgaben.

A rough translation, "They work determinedly for their success, they never give up and, therefore, overcome they most difficult tasks".
It's quite obvious that working hard is a good thing. And when you maintain this hard-working manner even when you face some headwinds, this is a good. So, *hartnäckig* has a positive meaning here.

I think that this word is quite equally common in spoken language as well as written texts. It's hard to prove this, though.

According to the [Wortschatz-Portal](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/), typical collocations are *Gerüchte*, *Vorurteile*, *Irrtümer*, *Klischees*, *Mythen* and the verbs *leugnen*, *weigern* and *(fest)halten*. This is what makes the word seem disapproving, because it's often used in a negative context.